# jQuery click on appended class

Tags: jquery, class, click, append

This has been addressed many times but the solutions found here still don't work in my case.

I use a jQuery script (Codecanyon Real3d flipbook) I bought which has its own js files.
This script appends a class on a span called '.flipbook-right-arrow'. And it has an "NextPage()" function applied on it.

What I would like to do is to add another event of mine, on top of the other event, in my own custom js file (the original minified script is too intricate and complicated for me to mess with).

So I started with the usual:

```
$('.flipbook-right-arrow').click(function(){
    alert()
})
```

It doesn't work and it seems normal because the class has been appended.

Ok, so, I read all over the place that this is the right way to do it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.flipbook-right-arrow', function() {
  alert();
});
```

But still nothing...

I also tried these, with no success:

```
$( ".flipbook-right-arrow" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert();
});

$( document ).delegate( ".flipbook-right-arrow", "click", function() {
  alert();
});

$('.flipbook-right-arrow').on('click', function(){
    alert();
});
```

Here is how the button is appended in the original script:

```
self.btnNext = jQuery('<div class="flipbook-nav"><div class="flipbook-arrow-wrapper"><span class="flipbook-right-arrow skin-color skin-color-bg"></div></div>')
    .appendTo(self.bookLayer)
    .bind('tap click', function(e) {

        if (self.btnNext.disabled) return;
        self.btnNext.disabled = true
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.btnNext.disabled = false;
        }, 300)

        e.stopPropagation(); //here was the problem!
        e.preventDefault();
        self.Book.nextPage();
    });
```

What is the problem?
Is it an event handling problem or a scope problem?
I just don't know. And I'm not savvy enough to think this through.

FYI:

- I also "e.prevenDefault()"-ed them, with no success.
- My custom js file is loaded after all the other scripts.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show how the class is appended.

Comment: I edited my initial post with the code. 
Note that even if I add the alert after "self.Book.nextPage();" in the original script, nothing will happen. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try closing your `<span>` (just in case)?

Comment: Good catch (it's in their script, not mine). But still nothing is happening.

Comment: Well, it seems the `click` event is caught by that same script you're using, which uses `stopPropagation` itself so it never goes up to `document` or any enclosing element. If you remove `stopPropagation` from there does it work (with your second approach)?

Comment: Nice! It was the problem and yes, it totally makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.flipbook-right-arrow').on('click', function(){
    alert()
});
```

also **make sure** that **"flipbook-right-arrow" is a class** because that's how you're calling it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to say that I tried this one too (I edited my post). And yes, it clearly a class. here is how it appears on the browser: "<span class="flipbook-right-arrow" title="Next page"></span>".

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if your event is event triggering:

```
$(document).on('click', '.flipbook-right-arrow', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    alert('Why hello there')
});
```

**NOTICE:** The `e` I passed as the argument for the function. That's the event. Now, we are trying to stop all the binded actions to that event by calling `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I jus tried, it makes sense, it but it doesn't work. The arrow keeps on doing it's thing but doesn't alert anything.

Comment: Hmm, is there any error in the console or something? Is this custom script even included in your page where you're trying to override it? Also, make sure your custom script is the last one in the queue so that it can override the main script.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The console doesn't mention anything. No errors there. My script is directly added to my page right now. And all of the other custom scripts of mine are working fine.
And my custom scripts are enclosed in the last "<script></script>" of my page so I assume they are read after anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Jeto found the problem (thank you).

The original script stopped the propagation of the event so I just got rid of that instruction and everything went fine.

Thank all of you for your help!